# How can i get formatted string of hour with no separators?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need a NSString from a NSDate, I only need the hour,minutes and seconds.
If it's 1:40:30 PM I need the string to be "134030"

```
NSDateFormatter *userTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[userTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss"];
```

This doesn't work. If I use the format hhmmss it seems to work but it's not in 24 hour format.
Any suggestions?
Might be something to do with locale?

Comment: Aside from not actually calling `stringFromDate` what isn't working about it?

Comment: time:3:49:16 pm... why are those separators there ...

Comment: `hh` or `HH` is a big difference. `hh` is in `12h format`, `HH` is in `24h format`

Comment: In your question you state: If it's 1:40:30 PM I need the string to be "1340330", should that be "134030" ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is Locale, set the correct Locale, Set the local of your NSDateFormatter to en_US_POSIX will fix this. It works for both 24-hour and 12 hour format.

```
   NSDateFormatter *userTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [userTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss"];
        NSLocale *en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        [userTimeFormatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];

        NSLog(@"time:%@",[userTimeFormatter stringFromDate:userTime]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this

```
NSDateFormatter *userTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[userTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss"];

NSLog(@"%@",[userTimeFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date=[dtFormatter dateFromString:"1:40:30 PM"];


[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss"];
NSString *dateString=[dtFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is Locale, set the correct Locale, Set the local of your NSDateFormatter to en_US_POSIX will fix this. It works for both 24-hour and 12 hour format.